# Null pointer after sorted database query

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying to query my database and sort my start column in descending order then get the first row.

```
public Cursor getLowestEvent(){
    String sort = "SELECT * FROM " + EVENTS_TABLE + " ORDER_BY " + START + " DESC";

    Cursor c = db.query(EVENTS_TABLE, new String[] {ID,START},null,null,null,null,sort); //error
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

doing this gives me a null pointer exception and I dont know why, there are items in the database so it has to be a problem with my sort?

```
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.app.notifyme.CalendarDB.getLowestEvent(CalendarDB.java:106)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.app.notifyme.Calendar$5.onClick(Calendar.java:162)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-25 11:03:14.503: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where do you get the null ref exception? Is it the retured c value?

Comment: Please post your logcat with line numbers if you want help. :)

Comment: updated with logcat and where error occurs

Comment: What exactly is on line 106? The db.query line? When debugging, what are the values of EVENTS_TABLE, ID, and START just before calling db.query? Also are you supposed to call db.open() or anything first? Maybe your db object is null.

Comment: @Jack wow that was the problem I missed opening the db before that, I threw that in and it now works. Funny how you miss the simplest things

Comment: Sweet, I added an edit detailing what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) link. Your last parameter (order by) is not supposed to be an ENTIRE sql statement (SELECT * FROM ...). It is supposed to be formatted as a SQL ORDER BY clause. Since it says exclude the ORDER BY itself, I think it would just be the column you want to order by and the identifier to determine which way to order ("ID DESC").

> How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding
>   the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order,
>   which may be unordered.

The way you are building your query (in the string "sort"), you could also execute [db.rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

EDIT: What resolved the issue was adding db.open() before the db.query() call.

Comment: I have tried 3 different sorting methods, the one you see above, `String sort = START + " COLLATE LOCALIZED DESC";` and `String sort = START+" DESC"` all with the same result

Answer (score 1):

I think following will work make sure that
1] Your database is created.
2] Table is exist.
3] Field what you are mentioned are exist.

```
Cursor c = db.query(EVENTS_TABLE, new String[] {ID,START},null,null,null,null,START + " DESC")
```

Comment: I am not using a content provider, this is my own database table

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a complete `SELECT ...` statement to `db.query()`. It looks like you should be using `db.rawQuery()` instead. Read the documentation for these functions to check what arguments they expect.